# Select timestamp difference by call status from a call attempts table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

I have a table collecting verification call cdrs like this in REDSHIFT:

```
name      | callid       | timestamp         | Anumber       | BNumber | Duration | Status
customerA |1631c40d-e397 |2017/01/01 03:01:00| +390123456789 | +440123456700 | 0 | aborted
customerA |8a12ca23-8728 |2017/01/01 03:02:00| +390123456789 | +440123456701 | 0 | aborted
customerB |54739440-c297 |2017/01/01 03:03:00| +440123456755 | +440123456780 | 0 | aborted
customerA |87e01f74-ce9e |2017/01/01 03:03:01| +390123456789 | +440123456700 | 1 | success
customerB |54739440-c297 |2017/01/01 03:03:02| +440123456755 | +440123456123 | 0 | aborted
customerB |1d192eb7-01b0 |2017/01/01 03:03:03| +440123456755 | +440123456123 | 1 | success
```

Each attempt is a call with a unique callid.
Re-attempt means: I call you, call fails, I call you again until call is successful. So If anumber calls bnumber 3 times but just the third one is successful, then I have 3 attempts of which 2 re-attempts failed.

I need to get:

- 1. Number of aborted calls globally which have been re-attempted in less than 5 sec
- 2. Number of aborted calls globally which have been re-attempted in less than 20 sec

e.g. 
customerA made 1000 calls globally in April 01-30, 2017. 600 successful, 300 failed, 100 aborted.
Among these (300+100) calls, how many of them got re-attempted in less than 5 sec (too quick) and 20 sec.

- 3. Number/percentage of re-attempts when a number fails

e.g. 
Say (300+100) calls were made to 200 individual number. 
I would like to know the percentage of those who actually retries on the same number. 
If 100 users just try once & failed, the remaining 100 users (so 50% here) tried on avg 3 times when their number failed to be verified.

The big issue here for me is that customerA's call1 call2 and call3 are not linked in any way. So if customerA makes a call using numberA to numberB and it fails (aborted or failed) then he can try again and again until one call goes 'successful'.

I not it's not easy to explain. hope it is clearer a bit now.

Results should be like this

```
customer | aborted_calls | percentage_aborted_5s | percentage_aborted_20s
customerA | 300 | 20 | 40
```

---

I was trying to calculate summing the attempt like this but it's not counting all the attempts for the same 'call' (anumber calling many times bnumber withouth success)

```
select a.anumber,a.bnumber, sum(stat) from
(
select anumber,bnumber,timestamp
,case when status=3 then 0 else 1 end stat --3 is aborted or failed
from mytable
 ) a
 inner join (select * from mytable
 )v 
 on a.anumber=v.anumber and a.bnumber=v.bnumber
 where  datediff(s,v.timestamp,a.timestamp)<=5
 group by a.anumber,a.bnumber
```

If I have a success, than the counting should start again from 0 .

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using? What is your expected result? Please provide a [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)! We cannot see 1k rows. Leave out columns not relevant to your query. What is the difference between calls successful, failed and aborted? I can only see success and aborted. What data realisation represents failed (in your example)? Do you need the results globally over all rows (all customers) or globally PER customer only?

Comment: it's REDSHIFT, as described above. It is similar to postgres, but no stored procedures etc. Aborted and failed are considered same here, so when a verification call doesn't work. Success means calls work ok. 'What data realisation represents failed (in your example)?' not sure what you mean. I need per customer (globally is a term the I got in the request but now you make me noticed it is useless, I need this calculation per customer)

Comment: if anumber calls bnumber 6 times and 5 fail(aborted,failed wathever) and 1 is succesfull, I have 6 attempts of which 5 re-attempt until I get a call successfully.these re-attemps are counted if they are done in <=5 sconds distance. If anumber calls cnumber it needs to be counted in another group of calls.

Comment: I know exactly what you are aiming at, but you need to clarify one extra thing: point 3 - I call you today now. I fail. I call you again in 2 weeks. Is that still a reattempt? Is there a cutoff time difference? Because if there is no cutoff - it's easy, if there is a time difference cutoff, it's harder.

Comment: Also - providing that sample data you pasted as CREATE TABLE and INSERTS would help a lot!

Comment: " 
I know exactly what you are aiming at, but you need to clarify one extra thing: point 3 - I call you today now. I fail. I call you again in 2 weeks. Is that still a reattempt?" Nope, 5 seconds and 20 seconds interval :) they want to know number of attempts done within interval of >=5 seconds from one and another and same with 20 seconds

Comment: Also, no cut off, you could have 60 aborted, 1 per second and a minute is passed, it's important to check recursively it last one is <=5 sec from the previous one etc. But I think with sql this is quite hard